# Must implement abstract method error, but it's there

Tags: java

Keep getting the error, I can't seem to figure out why, the abstract method  *is* implemented. I tried adding the keyword public, but that didn't help at all. I've read examples on the internet about abstract method, but mostl of them are `void`.

The abstract class:

```
public abstract class Osoba {

private String ime_prezime;
private char pol;

public Osoba(String ime_prezime, char pol) {
    this.ime_prezime=ime_prezime;
    this.pol=pol;

}

public String getImePrezime() { return ime_prezime; }
public void setImePrezime(String ime_prezime) { this.ime_prezime=ime_prezime; }

public char getPol() { return pol; }
public void setPol(char pol) { this.pol=pol; }



abstract int brojGodinaOsobe(Datum danasnji_datum);
}
```

And the subclass:

```
public class OsobaDatum extends Osoba{

private Datum datum_rodjenja;

public OsobaDatum(String ime_prezime, char pol, final Datum datum_rodjenja) {
    super(ime_prezime, pol);
    this.datum_rodjenja=datum_rodjenja;
}

public String toString() {
    return "OsobaDatum: \n" + "Ime i prezime: " + getImePrezime() +
            "\n" + "Pol: " + getPol() + "\nDatum rodjenja: "
           + datum_rodjenja.toString();
}

int brojGodina(Datum danasnji_datum) {

    if ( datum_rodjenja.getMesec() < danasnji_datum.getMesec() ) {
        return danasnji_datum.getGodina() - datum_rodjenja.getGodina();
    }

    else if (datum_rodjenja.getDan() <= danasnji_datum.getDan() && 
            datum_rodjenja.getMesec() == danasnji_datum.getMesec()) {
        return danasnji_datum.getGodina() - datum_rodjenja.getGodina();
    }

    else 
        return danasnji_datum.getGodina() - datum_rodjenja.getGodina() -1 ;

 }
```

}

Comment: What error, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, edited the file just now. Eclipse just keeps popping atthe top of the file: `The type OsobaDatum must implement the inherited abstract method`

Comment: 1. Please add the error message. 2. If the problem is that `OsobaDatum` must implement `int brojGodinaOsobe`, it is because the closest method the code appears to have is `int brojGodina(Datum danasnji_datum)`, which is not the same name.

Comment: You only show base Person class - there is no way to know how ymisimplemented derived class. Make sure to post [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abstract method's name is brojGodinaOsobe() and it looks like you only implemented a method called brojGodina(). Add the Osobe and you should be OK.

Comment: Oh God, it seems that was the case. My bad, seen too much code for today.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not overriding the method `brojGodinaOsobe(Datum danasnji_datum);` from Super class.

Change `brojGodina(Datum danasnji_datum)` to `brojGodinaOsobe(Datum danasnji_datum)` in the OsobaDatum class.

Regards.